# Changing active slider value in plotly doesn't change the displayed data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

How can I change the displayed data subset when using `animation_frame`? `fig.update_layout(sliders=[dict(active=...)])`, shown in the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express), only changes the value selected on the slider itself, but not the actual data. In this example, it's still showing the data associated with `z=1` ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fbk84s5kiGWkivYznqy8S2HFfJRXaI5i?usp=sharing)).

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 1, 0, 1],
                       y=[0, 1, 1, 0],
                       z=[0, 0, 1, 1]))

fig = px.line(df, "x", "y", animation_frame="z")
fig.update_layout(sliders=[dict(active=1)])
fig.show()
```

[image]

(Also filed https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3276).